# xpages computed field displaying date and time

Tags: field, xpages

I have a computed field ( Display type: String ):

```
return currentDocument.getDocument().getCreated()
```

And I get something like this: `04/23/2014 10:08:08 AM ZE2.` Is there any chance I can get off the `ZE2` word? I tried changing the Display type to `Date/Time` but after this the computed field value is empty.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.toJavaDate()`. So do this instead:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" 
value="#{javascript:return currentDocument.getDocument().getCreated().toJavaDate()}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

Alternatively, use `@Created()`, so:

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:@Created()}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="both"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Per Henrik.